# Aperture 3 Library from pre Mavericks to Mavericks

Tags: macos, aperture

I made a backup from all my files including my Aperture library. After moving to Mavericks (clean install), there is a new Aperture version and I am not able to import my old library getting the message: Library was made with older version of Aperture, please update to newest version and try again (loosely translated from german). How should I do this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is easy: Open the library, you will be asked to update it. Do it. Than one can import it.